# Error in saving csv to MySQL table due to NULL values

Tags: mysql, database

I have the data saved in my csv excel. The data have some null value in row and column. I want to save this data into my database in MySQL. But null value is causing problem in saving the data to MySQL. This is the query for creating the table -

```
create table student (
  Std_ID int, 
  Roll_NO int, 
  First_Name varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
  Last_Name varchar(10), 
  Class int, 
  constraint test_student primary key (Std_ID)
);
```

...and it ran successfully. Now I want to save my data from csv to this table using the query -

```
load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\new.csv' into table student fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines;
```

...and is giving me the error msg -

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'XXX' at row X.
```

For the reference you can use [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12MJ2o4BaIcG6VFsp0YUQ2j5SjTqCJtUp/view?usp=sharing) data.
The same can be find below.
[image]

Comment: Is this a manual upload? Or do you need to script this. One thing I might do is create all `varchar` type fields in the database, import the CSV, then change the necessary fields to `int` in the database.

Comment: The error tells that the problematic value is **not NULL but empty string**. You must use input preprocessing for to solve. PS. What value do you want to insert instead this incorrect one? zero? NULL? etc.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles This is no script defined for this and regarding changing all columns to varchar, it's causing some issue when I extract the data in python.

Comment: @Akina The data is NULL it's not correct or incorrect. Since the data is empty string, what pre-processing can be done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\new.csv' 
INTO TABLE student 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED by '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
-- specify columns, use variables for the columns where incorrect value may occur
(Std_ID, @Roll_NO, First_Name, Last_Name, @Class)
-- use preprocessing, replace empty string with NULL but save any other value
SET Roll_NO = NULLIF(@Roll_NO, ''),
    Class = NULLIF(@Class, '');
```

If some column in CSV is empty string then NULL value will be inserted into according column of the table.

`Std_ID` is not preprocessed because it is defined as PRIMARY KEY, and it cannot be NULL.

---

### UPDATE

OP provides source file sample. Viewing it in HEX mode shows that the file is Windows-style text file, and hence the lines terminator is `'\r\n'`. After according edition the file is imported successfuly.

[image]

Comment: the query is still causing a problem. There is no error msg but the query isn't getting executed. After entering the query, I'm getting the msg '' for column 'Class' at row 4 integer value: '' and the query doesn't executes.

Comment: Edit your question and add a sample of your CSV file content (3-5 rows) formatted as code. *I'm getting the msg* You must provide complete and unchanged error message, not a small part of it.

Comment: Data has been added in the question, it was there in the link in question and the statement is not a part of the error, it's complete. You can see the below statements. That's what I'm getting
mysql> load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\SQL_Try.csv' into table student fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines (Std_Id, @Roll_No, First_Name, Second_Name, @Class) set Roll_No=NULLIF(@Roll_No,''), Class=NULLIF(@Class,'');
' for column 'Class' at row 4 integer value: '
mysql>

Comment: @Vikeshk Well, I look at your source data. You can easily look at the problem source. When the query fails the variable `@Class` stores the most last loaded value which causes an error. I.e. immediately after errorneous attempt execute `SELECT HEX(@Class)` - and you will see that the variable contains `0D` value. If you open the file in HEX viewer then you can see that each line is terminated with `0D 0A` bytes (the text is Window-style text) which has lines terminator `\r\n` whereas you tell MySQL that `LINES TERMINATED by '\n'`. So this is **your** error, not query error.

Comment: I didn't understood completely, I'll try to understand this but why it's causing problem only for the last column not for the column Roll_No?

Comment: @Vikeshk Study the difference between Windows-style text and Unix-style text, pay attention to lines terminator difference. The answer is updated.